# "C" Trying to understand **pointer and how to access all values of value[][]

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic, double-pointer

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int *pI, *values[2];
    int i1[] = {1, 2}, i2[][2] = {{5, 10}, {20, 30}};
// SOME LINES ARE EDITED, AFTER READING COMMENTS
    *values = i2[*i1];          // i2[1] = 20 // values[0] = &i2[1][0];
    values[1] = i1;             // values[1] = 1 
    pI = &i2[0][0];             //pI = 5
    printf(" %d %d\n", **values, *&values[1][1]); //...
    // (Edited) expectation: **values = 20 *&values[1][1] = 2
    // Result:               **values = 20 *&values[1][1] = 2
    
    *pI += pI[i1[1]];           // pI[0] += pI[2] = 5 + 20 = 25
    *values = pI;               // values points to the 25 (pI)
    *(i1 + 1) *= *(values[1] + 1);  // i1[1]=2 // i1[1] *= i1[1] = 2*2
    printf(" %d %d\n", **values, *&values[1][1]);
    // (Edited) expectation: **values = 25 *&values = 4
    // Result:               **values = 25 *&values = 4

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see my understanding of this code is not the yellow from the egg.
But I would like to understand the steps, that i can solve it by myself the next time

Comment: _"the yellow from the egg"_ (?!)

Comment: You know that `*&values[1][1]` is the same as `values[1][1]`?

Comment: There is no *"double pointer"*, there are **pointer to pointer(s)**. Pointers are address that points to something (think about an internet link), one pointer may points to one or more other pointers; this is the sens of `**`. You can *dereference* pointer by array subscript `[]` or (more common for a single value) using the `*` operator. Given the **valid** pointer `int* num;` then  `*num = 1` is equivalent to `num[0] = 1`. Transpose the logic for *"nested"* pointers. Continue try and experiment step by step.

Comment: Now I know :D Thx Weather

Comment: There's a lot of issues here. I started to write an answer but as I read your code it became obvious that you don't have a clue about how plain arrays work in the first place. You'll simply have to double back and read the chapter about arrays in your C book, before concerning yourself with pointers and multi-dimensional arrays. Most importantly, if you don't understand that arrays in C start with index 0, you'll not understand anything else about this code either.

Comment: @Lundin y i realised myself looking at the i2[1] that its the 2nd element of the array, not the first. brainlag

Comment: should have split this into 2 seperate questions. Trying to understand both at the same time isn´t smart

Comment: @Weather Vane Eclipse says *&values[1][1] = 2. But shouldn´t it be 30 if *&values[1][1] is the same as values[1][1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `*values` is the same as `values[0]` due to the definition of the subscript operator.

Thus this statement

```
*values = i2[*i1];
```

may be rewritten the following way

```
values[0] = i2[i1[0]];
```

As i1[0] yields the value 1 then

```
values[0] = i2[1];
```

The expression i2[1] yields the second element of the array i2 that is the one-dimensional array of the type `int[2]` with values `{20, 30}`.

Array designators used in expression with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. So you may write

```
values[0] = &i2[1][0];
```

Thus the value of the expression `**values` is equal to 20.

Again in this statement

```
values[1] = i1;
```

the array designator i1 is converted to pointer to its first element. That is you may write

```
values[1] = &i1[0];
```

In this expression `*&values[1][1]` the pair of operators *& in fact does not have an effect. You may write  `values[1][1]`.  So this expression yields the second element of the array `i1` that is equal to `2`.

The variable `pI`

```
pI = &i2[0][0];
```

points to the element `&i2[0][0]`. This record may be interpreted as

```
pI = ( int * )i2;
```

This statement

```
*pI += pI[i1[1]];
```

may be rewritten like

```
*pI += pI[2];
```

The value of pI[2] is 20 (the third element of the type `int` of the array `i2`.
SP you have

```
*pI += 20;
```

As a result the element `i2[0][0]` will contain `25`.

This statement

```
 *values = pI;
```

is equivalent to

```
values[0] = pI;
```

So now the pointer `values[0]` points to the element `i2[0][0]` that is to the value `25` that is outputted using the expression `**values`.

This expression statement

```
*(i1 + 1) *= *(values[1] + 1);
```

may be rewritten like

```
i1[1] *= *( values[1] + 1 );
```

Due to the statement above

```
values[1] = i1;
```

`values[1]` points to the first element of the array `i1`. So the expression `values[1] + 1` points to the second element of the array `i1` that is equal to `2`.

So you have

```
i1[1] *= 2;
```

As a result `i1[1]` is equal to `4`.

This value is outputted by the expression `*&values[1][1]` that as it was mentioned above is equivalent to `values[1][1]`

To understand the pointer arithmetic and the implicit conversion of array designators to pointers to their first elements there is no need to write such an obfuscated code.